# how do you generate an ONNX representation of a pytorch bert pretrained neural network?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, torch, onnx

I am trying to generate an ONNX file for the [pytorch-pretrained-bert](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT) run_classifier.py example.

In this case, I'm running it with the following parameters as per the main README.md:

```py
export GLUE_DIR=/tmp/glue_data

python run_classifier.py \
  --task_name MRPC \
  --do_train \
  --do_eval \
  --do_lower_case \
  --data_dir $GLUE_DIR/MRPC/ \
  --bert_model bert-base-uncased \
  --max_seq_length 128 \
  --train_batch_size 32 \
  --learning_rate 2e-5 \
  --num_train_epochs 3.0 \
  --output_dir /tmp/mrpc_output/
```

The following code is modified/added at line 552:

```py
    # Save a trained model
    model_to_save = model.module if hasattr(model, 'module') else model  # Only save the model it-self
    output_model_file = os.path.join(args.output_dir, "pytorch_model.bin")
    if args.do_train:
        torch.save(model_to_save.state_dict(), output_model_file)

    # Save ONNX
    msl = args.max_seq_length
    dummy_input = torch.randn(1, msl, msl, msl, num_labels, device="cpu")
    output_onnx_file = os.path.join(args.output_dir, "classifier.onnx")
    torch.onnx.export(model, dummy_input, output_onnx_file)
```

The dummy_input is supposed to correspond to the bert pretrained model inputs. A sample_batch_size of 1 seems suitable for my needs, I think.

A few suggest that the arguments should match the arguments to the models forward() method. In this case:

```py
class BertForSequenceClassification(PreTrainedBertModel):
    def forward(self, input_ids, token_type_ids=None, attention_mask=None, labels=None):
```

In this case, I believe the ranks are:

```
input_ids: 1 x 128 <the max_seq_length specified in the args>
token_type_ids: 1 x max_seq_length
attention_mask: 1 x max_seq_length
labels: 1 x 2 <the number of labels for MRPC>
```

so the effective call is:

```py
    dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 128, 128, 128, 2, device="cpu")
```

Unfortunately this produces an error:

```
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
The expanded size of the tensor (2) must match the existing size (128) at non-singleton dimension 4.  Target sizes: [1, 128, 128, 128, 2].  Tensor sizes: [1, 128]
```

It seems likely that it's something fairly straightforward. Suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Did you manage to get your model converted to ONNX? I haven't been able to get past what appears to be a memory error: `builtins.RuntimeError: [enforce fail at CPUAllocator.cpp:56] posix_memalign(&data, gAlignment, nbytes) == 0. 12 vs 0`. I'll actually be making a smaller model, using custom data, so I don't need something as large as the pretrained version, but I wanted to be sure I could convert it to ONNX before spending a bunch of time on the custom model and data.